# テストを実行しているときに "Could not find a JavaScript runtime." が出てしまう場合の対処法について

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

Railsの開発をしている際に、`rbenv`を利用しながら開発をしているのですが、ちょっとしたトラブルがあり、新しく開発環境を一新しました。

そのとき、`bundle install`をしたあとに、`./bin/rake test`を動かしていると、下のようなエラーが出てしまいます:

```
FoobarsControllerTest#test_should_get_new:
ActionView::Template::Error: c See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs for a list of available runtimes.
 (in /home/esehara/.rbenv/versions/2.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/turbolinks-2.5.3/lib/assets/javascripts/turbolinks.js.coffee)
  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:6:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__3074344629272133642_70077899278000'
  test/controllers/foobar_controller_test.rb:16:in `block in <class:FoobarsControllerTest>'
```

以前の環境では、上記のようなエラーは発生していなかったと記憶しています。このような、`execjs`が必要になってしまう理由は一体なんなのでしょうか。また、これに対しての根本的な対処法とはどのようなものでしょうか。

参考のため、以下の`rbenv`の環境で`bundle install`を行いましたが、どれを使ってもエラーとなってしまいます:

- `ruby 2.1.0`
- `ruby 2.2.0`
- `ruby 2.2.1`

このエラーの解決方法についての、正しい対処法があれば、是非教えてください。

Answer (score 2):

"See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs for a list of available runtimes."や"execjs node.js"みたいなキーワードでググると似たようなエラーがいろいろと上がってきます。
以前、僕の知り合いも同じようなエラーで困っていました。

その際はnode.jsを再インストールしたら直ったように記憶しています。
（「新しく開発環境を一新」とあるので、そういったミドルウェアのセットアップも必要になる気がします）

いくつか情報源のリンクを載せておきますので、いろいろ試してみてください。

- http://babydaemons.hatenablog.com/entry/20110920/Rails3_on_Ubuntu
- http://qiita.com/timadayon/items/21201378bbb6034c9edb
- http://qiita.com/yamazaki/items/ac9c6f7ac1d6041f4ab8
- http://babydaemons.hatenablog.com/entry/20110920/Rails3_on_Ubuntu
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6282307/execjs-and-could-not-find-a-javascript-runtime

うまくいったら有効だった対応を教えてください。